# Requirements for a Markov system to be optimal

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

This seems a very basic question, but recently after coming across this question that what are the requirements for a Markov system to be optimal, I found myself to be confused. These are what comes to mind:

1. It has to have a Markov strategy, i.e., *Ut=gt(Xt)*, where *t* is for time
2. State-space, action space, and the noise space all need to be Borel space
3. The cost function (or the reward function) must be measurable.

Am I correct in identifying the requirements? Correct me if I am wrong - your input will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Your question is very vague - what exactly do you mean by "Markov system," and what is to be optimized?